# Inaccessable Ubuntu Partition

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, partitioning

I am having a bit of trouble with my Ubuntu installation, I am a Linux Noob so please excuse me.

I installed Ubuntu, disabled fast boot, partitioned the disk removing the pre-installed Windows 8.

It ran successfully for a few weeks, but yesterday my laptop froze so I did a hard reset. When I booted it back up I was met with a grub screen giving me the choice of loading a Ubuntu previous installation, continuing to my existing installation, going to BIOS or opening the terminal.

Whichever Ubuntu install I chose would error on me and display `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist` alongside a few other errors like `check root delay`.

I ran `boot-repair` and shut down the machine. Now my issue is my BIOS lists my Ubuntu installation as found but it will not load at all (Drive not present)

I've then run `testdisk` and it is finding the Ubuntu partition, but I don't know how to remap my BIOS to find it!

[Here you can find the boot repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10863387/)

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** In the boot-repair log, only the EFI boot of the USB stick can be found...  It looks like your hard drive was damaged during the *very hard reset*; can you mount the HDD in an external enclosure and see whether the light comes up and listen whether it makes any sound like spinning up? Did you originally install the system in EFI mode?

Comment: Hi Fabby, thanks for cleaning up my question. In response, no I do not believe I used (U)EFI mode to install the OS. I have not got a HDD mount with me currently but I have managed to get a LiveUSB to work and I have used gparted to verify that the HDD is working and being picked up. [Here is a screenshot of Parted showing the drive] (http://i.imgur.com/fp3hkqL.png) Parted will not let me attempt a data recovery because 'This feature uses gpart. Please install gpart and try again.'

Comment: *update* I have manged to install photorec to my liveCD but this only allows me to select file types to recover - not files / folders. Is there a better recovery tool I should be using?

Comment: Did you encrypt your data? You seem to be using Logical Volume Manager (LVM)...

Comment: I dont think any of the data is encrypted, at least if it is it's with a very weak password that I remember. Will I have to decrypt the drive before I can access it if it is encrypted?

Comment: I don't use encryption, so cannot help you any further...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell your pasted information is from a regular live cd. It says something about squashfs which is a compressed file system that is hardly used in a regular environment. In a menu entry it says something about testing Ubuntu without installing which is a dead giveaway that we're dealing with a live cd.

I suspect you didn't install at all to your hard drive or at least you appear to only have the live cd version right now and I recommend to insert the live cd again then really install Ubuntu and see what it says about a possible existing install.

Comment: I did have a fully working version of Ubuntu for a few weeks before this recover using parted but it tells me gpart is not installed